# Login to the site through scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I do an official video lesson authorization on the site.
If the username and password are incorrect, then the transition to the callback method is successful, if the login and password are correct, then the transition to the method is not feasible.
My code:
import scrapy

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ["https://www.darkorbit.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        login_url = response.css('form[name="bgcdw_login_form"]::attr(action)').extract_first()
        data = {
            'username': 'testscrapy',
            'password': 'testtest',
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=login_url, formdata=data, callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        print('----------------------------------------')
```

With the correct input data, a log is obtained(Long fragments are cut):

```
2017-06-03 22:04:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.darkorbit.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-03 22:04:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.darkorbit.com> (referer: None)
2017-06-03 22:04:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://auth3.bpsecure.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-03 22:04:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.darkorbit.com/ProjectAp........>
2017-06-03 22:04:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://ru4.darkorbit.com/Pro..........>
2017-06-03 22:04:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ru4.darkorbit.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-03 22:04:43 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://ru4.darkorbit.com/Pro......>
```

Comment: ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False it help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From this line of your logs:

```
2017-06-03 22:04:43 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://ru4.darkorbit.com/Pro......>
```

I can tell that you need to change a setting in you **settings.py** file.

The variable `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` needs to be set at `False`

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
```